# ASP .NET Core MVC: What happens to a request on RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I was trying to pass data around between controllers all day long, but now I'm at the point where I think I haven't quite understood the basics.

Throughout the documentation of ASP .NET core, they use the word "request". I was under the assumption that this is the HttpRequest that is made by the client of the WebServer.

There are also different things that are supposed to be bound to the lifetime of a request:

- The `HttpContext` and its `HttpContext.Items` dictionary.
- Services added with `AddScoped` via dependency injection.
- The `TempData` dictionary? (not so sure about that)

But when trying to pass data around, I made the observation that when I do `return RedirectToAction(...);` the `HttpContext` changes (`HttpContext.GetHashCode()` has a different value), `TempData` changes and services added via `AddScoped` are also new objects.

That would suggest that on `RedirectToAction` a new request is made, going through all the steps of the request pipeline again. My expectation though was that a `RedirectToAction` only continues the current request pipeline with a different controller action.

I also thought that the browser or whatever client only made one request and got one response during that entire process.

So what is actually happening when calling `RedirectToAction` in a controller action and returning the result?

**UPDATE:**
Using TempData works, but a TempDataProvider has to be configured first. For example add `services.AddSingleton<ITempDataProvider,SessionStateTempDataProvider>();` to `Startup.cs`. Thanks @RonC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, `RedirecToAction` will cause the browser to make a new request, and when that new request comes in, it will create a totally new `HttpContext`.  As mentioned, To pass data between the two requests, you can use the query string, session or cookies. But there is another option to consider.

**TempData**
Data can be passed from one request to another via the `TempData` collection which is accessible in the controller action method.  The `TempData` collection was specifically designed for passing data from one request to another.  The beauty of `TempData` is that the lifetime of an object placed in `TempData` is exactly one additional request.  So anything placed in `TempData` in request 1 will be there for request 2 but then be automatically removed from `TempData` at the conclusion of request 2.  This makes `TempData` perfect for passing data from one request to another without having to disclose that information in a query string or possibly forgetting it in session and bloating the session object.

Comment: I was actually trying to use TempData for that, but it didn't work. But I read something about the contents being removed on first access, might that be the problem? Also I accessed it inside an implementation of 'IActionFilter', not inside of the controller action itself.

Comment: I haven't worked with action filters yet but that could well be your issue if it's removed on first access (which would kinda make sense).  So you should probably give it a try by accessing it in the next request in the action method without first accessing it in the action filter.  If you really need to access it in the action filter then you could re-add it to temp data or add it to the request items collection. So that it's available to the action method.

Comment: No, TempData doesn't keep my data, even if I only access it once.

Comment: Have you set up session support?  TempData uses session typically.  There is now a cookie based TempData provider as well in .Net Core 1.1.  You will need to enable one of those for TempData to work.

Comment: Thanks. Now it works. I had registered the session, but not SessionStateTempDataProvider. I think this is bad design, it should throw an exception when attempting to use TempData without a TempDataProvider being configured.

Comment: I agree with that, it should totally throw an exception in such a case.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to save state of current request, because... HTTP is stateless. Every `RedirectToAction` really tells browser to make another HTTP request. As [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx) says.

> Returns an HTTP 302 response to the browser, which causes the browser to make a GET request to the specified action.

If you would like to pass some data between HTTP requests, you have to use cookies or session mechanism.

Comment: `RedirectToAction` also allows you to pass data on the query string via `routeValues`.

Comment: @Jasen But the route values are just the ones used for modelbinding (to my understanding). I think I will have to serialize my object and store it in the session.

Comment: And there seems to be no documentation of the .NET Core version of RedirectToAction, but it looks like it works in the same way.

Comment: Yes, you won't pass objects over the query string but you can say, pass the item id, then lookup the the id in the following actions.

Comment: @FSMaxB it has to work the same way, because this behaviour is caused by HTTP nature :-)

Comment: @PawełHemperek I meant the API of the RedirectToAction function.